# SharePoint web services to create folders issue

Tags: web-services

we have a java application which will create folders and copy files from other system to SharePoint through web services.

This application is working fine is windows 7 Enterprise version,but the same app is not working on windows server 2008 R2, we are always getting

> "folder not found"

issue while invoking `CreateFolder` webservice. We are using jdk1.7+, SharePoint 2010, win server 2008 R2. Any pointers would be great help.

Comment: What parameter are you passing to create folder? Check the library name and the properties passed...for creating it should not say Folder not found